# Randomly not able to get embedded object field values using morphia createQuery

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

This happens randomly and I cannot predict it and need help with suggestions. Looking at the simple `Entity` below the field `hash` does exist in Mongo when viewing the `Collection` using MongoVUE. Inserting 10 `slice'es` into the LinkedHashMap is working ok and everything looks ok when looking at the db in MongoDb MOngoVUE. When creating the `Query` If I insert 10 I get 10 out but on the last 5 (5,6,7..) the field `hash` is empty.

The `Collection` `BatchClass` does only have one Document and that is this one im running tests on. What can cause this behaviour?

Running test: Saving same data 5 times and 3 of this times the `hash` field is empty when running the `Query` .(in MonGOVUE the field `hash` has the desired value on all 5 tests..

Does MongoDB have log files I can investigate?

Creating a `Query`  :

```
Query<BatchClass> query = mongo.createQuery(BatchClass.class);
query.field(BatchClass.BATCHUUID).equal(theBatch.getBatchUuid());           
query.field(BatchClass.POSITION).equal(position);           
res = (BatchClass) query.get();
```

The `Entity`  :

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored=true)
public final class BatchClass{

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Embedded
    private LinkedHashMap<Integer, Slice> sliceTable = null;

    public void insertSlice(int pos, Slice slice) {
        sliceTable.put(pos,slice);
    }

    public Map<Integer, Slice> getSliceTable() {
        return sliceTable;
    }

    @Entity(noClassnameStored=true)
    @Embedded
    public static class Slice
    {
        public int keyPosition; 
        public String sliceName;          
        public String  hash;  
        public int sliceFileSize;       
        public boolean completed = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: The read operation that failed happened 30-60 sec after the write. Since MongoDb flushes to disk at an 60sec interval that could be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read operation that failed happened 30-60 sec after the write. Since MongoDb flushes to disk at an 60sec interval that could be the reason.